# Google Forms uploaded file is stored two times in gDrive

Tags: file-upload, google-drive-api, google-forms

I have a Google Form with 3 fields and 1 upload file field, which is linked to a Google spreadsheet.

Every time I submit the form, my attachment is stored twice in my gDrive folders, one is in the root folder (the original file), and the other one is in the right Form_Name (File Responses), the renamed file (see script).

Both the Google Form and the Responses are inside a shared folder.

I have a script running on form submit (with a trigger) which renames the file before saving it, using some of the other submitted fields, tho only the one in Form_Name (File Responses) is renamed.

My need is to only keep the renamed file and delete the one in my gDrive root folder.

This is my script.

```
function onFormSubmit(e){ 

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];

    switch(itemResponse.getItem().getTitle()){

      case "Time":
        var timeString = itemResponse.getResponse();
        break;

      case "Author":
        var authorString = "_" + itemResponse.getResponse();
        break;

      case "Type":
        var typeString = "_" + itemResponse.getResponse();
        break;  

      case "Setup.ini file":
        var fileId = itemResponse.getResponse();
        break;
    }

  }

  var fileNameString = timeString + typeString + authorString;

  Logger.log('renameFile('+fileId+','+fileNameString+');');
  console.log('renameFile('+fileId+','+fileNameString+');');

  renameFile(fileId,fileNameString);
}


function renameFile(id,fileName) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  file.setName(fileName);
}
```

Comment: Is this thread useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56171896

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find it. I was somehow focusing on avoiding the duplicate entry rather than just deleting it afterwards. I'll update with the full working code!

Answer (score 0):

**Working code! Thanks to this thread found by Tanaike ->** [stackoverflow.com/q/56171896](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171896/remove-google-form-submitted-file)

```
function onFormSubmit(e){ 

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formResponses = form.getResponses();
  var formResponse = formResponses[formResponses.length-1];
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];

    switch(itemResponse.getItem().getTitle()){

      case "Time":
        var timeString = itemResponse.getResponse();
        break;

      case "Author":
        var authorString = "_" + itemResponse.getResponse();
        break;

      case "Stint":
        var typeString = "_" + itemResponse.getResponse();
        break;  

      case "Setup.ini file":
        var fileId = itemResponse.getResponse();
        var uploadedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId);
        var uploadedFileName = uploadedFile.getName();
        break;
    }

  }

  var fileNameString = timeString + typeString + authorString;

  Logger.log('renameFile('+fileId+','+fileNameString+');');
  Logger.log('thrashRootFile('+uploadedFileName+');');
  console.log('renameFile('+fileId+','+fileNameString+');');
  console.log('thrashRootFile('+uploadedFileName+');');

  renameFile(fileId,fileNameString);
  thrashRootFile(uploadedFileName);

}


function renameFile(id,fileName) {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
  file.setName(fileName);
}


function thrashRootFile(fileName){
  var p1 = fileName.split(" - ");
  var extension = p1[p1.length - 1];
  p1.pop();
  var name = p1.join(" - ");
  var p2 = "";
  if (extension.indexOf(".") > -1) {
    p2 = "." + extension.split(".")[1];
  }
  var orgFilename = name + p2;

  // Move uploaded file to the trash.
  var orgFiles = DriveApp.getRootFolder().getFilesByName(orgFilename);
  if (orgFiles.hasNext()) {
    var orgFile = orgFiles.next();
    orgFile.setTrashed(true);
  }
}
```