# Upload file using a form. Moving a file to a specific folder issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

High School teacher here with hardly any experience in GAS or Javascript. Using a google form to have students upload a file(s). The file gets moved to an assignment folder in a period folder based off what the student enters. The file should get renamed so that it has the student's name in Last First name order at the beginning of the file.

All of that is working! BUT for some reason it is giving me two versions of the file! One in the correct place, but another one in the root directory of my Google Form. What is wrong with my code?

```
function myFunction2() {
  const folderId = "";  // I deleted the ID since I don\'t know if there is any privacy issues
 
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();                                           //gets the form
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();                                      //gets all the responses
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length-1].getItemResponses(); //gets the last response
 
  // Prepare the folder names
  const rootFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);                             //root folder
  const periodName = itemResponses[1].getResponse();                               //period name
  const assignmentName = itemResponses[2].getResponse();                           //assignment name
 
  // Checks to see if the period folder exists
  const periodIterator = rootFolder.getFoldersByName(periodName);                                               //Folder iterator
  const periodFolder = periodIterator.hasNext() ? periodIterator.next() : rootFolder.createFolder(periodName);  //does the period Folder exist?
 
  // Checks to see if the assignment folder in the period exists
  const assignmentIterator = periodFolder.getFoldersByName(assignmentName);                                     //Assignment iterator
  const assignmentFolder = assignmentIterator.hasNext() ? assignmentIterator.next() : periodFolder.createFolder(assignmentName);//does the assignment folder exist
 
  // Puts all files in the Period/Assignment folder
  // Renames files so that it has Last Name, First Name order at beginning of the name
  files = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
  if (files.length > 0) {
    for (var n in files) {
      var dFile = DriveApp.getFileById(files[n]);
      var fullFileName = dFile.getName();
     
      var firstPart = fullFileName.substring(0, fullFileName.lastIndexOf("-")-1);
      var namePart = fullFileName.substring(fullFileName.lastIndexOf("-")+2, fullFileName.lastIndexOf("."));
 
      var firstName = namePart.substring(0,namePart.indexOf(" "));
      var lastName = namePart.substring(namePart.indexOf(" ")+1);
      var flippedName = lastName+", "+firstName;
 
      dFile.setName(flippedName+" - "+ firstPart);      //Rename the file
      dFile.moveTo(assignmentFolder);                   //Move the file
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `two versions of the file`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: There are two copies of the file. One file is the renamed file in the correct sub directory. The other file has the same name as the original file and is in the root directory of my google drive.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In that case, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56171896/7108653

Comment: Just realized that I never came back to this. My original code worked! The problem was that this was during the winter break and couldn't get a student to test it. On my account it caused the error.