# Apps Script: getting copy of original file when using DriveApp setName() to rename

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm using a Google Form for festival participants to upload a waiver after signing. I am trying to rename the file they upload with the participant's name and upload time to keep the folder organized but I am having issues.

The renamed files are appearing properly in the child folder they were uploaded to, but they are also appearing in my root drive folder with their original name. Please see my code below.

**Code**:

```
function waiverSubmissionFileId(participantName) {

const waiverSubmissionFolderId = '***DRIVE*FOLDER*ID***',
      waiverSubmissionFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(waiverSubmissionFolderId);

var lastSubmittedFileInfo = retrieveLastFileId(waiverSubmissionFolder);
var lastSubmittedFileId = lastSubmittedFileInfo[0],
    lastSubmittedFileType = lastSubmittedFileInfo[1];
var lastSubmittedFile = DriveApp.getFileById(lastSubmittedFileId);
var currentTime = new Date();
var currentTimeFormatted = Utilities.formatDate(currentTime,"GMT-5", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");
lastSubmittedFile.setName(currentTimeFormatted + ' - ' + participantName + '.' + lastSubmittedFileType);
}

function retrieveLastFileId(waiverSubmissionFolder) {
var files = waiverSubmissionFolder.getFiles();;
var result = [];
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  var dateCreated = new Date().valueOf();
  var fileId = file.getId();
  result.push([dateCreated,fileId]);
 } 
var id = result.sort()[0][1];
 var fileType = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getContentType().slice(-3);
 if (fileType == 'peg'){
var fileInfo = [id,'jpg'];
 }
 else{
 var fileInfo = [id,fileType];
 }
  return fileInfo;
};
```

I was originally using `getItemResponses()` to rename the file. It worked fine with a PDF but didn't work with a jpg or png. I decided to just rename the last uploaded file *(script is locked while it's running anyway)* and thought I was successful until I noticed the files in my root folder.

---

> Could `getBlob()` be creating a duplicate file in the root folder of my Drive?

Comment: In your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/56171896

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, that's a well documented and organized post. Turns out my problem was much simpler - and a little silly. I was organizing my Drive folders, I moved the form response folder, confirmed files were still being uploaded and renamed. I later noticed the duplicate files on my root drive. Forms forced the original folder structure back, after my manipulation, and all is well.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, your issue has already been resolved. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue is resolved, how about posting it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution:

I had moved the file responses folder. The folder ID still existed, but the Form was no longer linked to the folder. I restored the Forms link to the upload folder and it now works fine.